# How to create a custom search dialog in SherlockActionBar?

Tags: android, android-layout

well i have implemented Search dialog by referring to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html).
every thing is working fine.

-i'm using SherLockActionBar.

-i'm getting the search dialog in Action bar itself.

[image]

-but i want it to drop-down when i click seach icon on ActionBar, the search dialog must appear below the actionbar

[image]

can any one help me out.

ThankQ.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to customize your layout according that.Just like Visibility.Gone and Visibility.Visible.
Download this, if this is not what you are asking post a comment.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z67pmzbvwoj4oge/ShowHide.zip

Comment: instead of hiding can we make it to slide down..?

Comment: ya...we can..but for that too initially it should be hidden..but once you tapped we can animate the view..

Comment: How can i animate it to drop down,do you have any idea ?

Comment: ok..i tel u...wen u click on the button, use this code  
  Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourClassName.this, R.anim.pullfromtop);
 a.setDuration(2000);       
        a.reset();
        dropdownview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drop);
        dropdownview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 
      dropdownview.clearAnimation();
     dropdownview.startAnimation(a);

Comment: create a folder anim in res directory  and add this : pullinfromtop.xml , <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <scale
  android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.3"
  android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.3"
  android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="100%"
  android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
 />
 <alpha
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
  android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
  android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
 />
</set>

Comment: you can add whatever animation you want for that dropdown view